# onKeyDown() issue

Tags: android, android-view, onkeydown

I would like to create a photo/video capture application.

I have created a `CaptureView` class which extends `SurfaceView` and placed it in the main form.

The main form's activity has `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method which creates a menu. The menu worked fine but then I tried to implement a method `onKeyDown`:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch(keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA:
            videoPreview.TakePicture();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

The menu doesn't appear anymore and the method doesn't catch onKeyDown event.

Does anyone know what could be the reason for this issue?

Comment: If you comment out the if statement is the menu still not shown?

Comment: I tried to comment out the if statement but as expected nothing changed.

Comment: I just found out there was some exception not related to the code above stopping the execution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found that I was returning **`true`** for all events, where I should only have been returning it for the code that I was using. I moved the return true inside the scope of the **`if`** statement and returned **`false`** otherwise That brought my menu back!

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        dba.close();
        Intent result = new Intent("Complete");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry always returning false used to work in older SDK but will lead to trouble: when compiling with ICS, this approach will disable the back key. of course in your specific case it is working as you are precisely consumming back key event, but in generally it will not work as expected.

Comment: -1. The best answer involves 'return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);', instead of always returning false when you don't handle the key down, as posted by rrabio.

Comment: The onKeyDown() method is not at all called while pressing the hardware search button, instead search default behaviour is triggered. But pressing back or menu button trigger this method. How can I listen the android hardware search button click.?

Comment: I'm having the same problem but only the second time I push KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN and I made a "temporary" workaround by adding it to the switch statements in the key cases and only returning it with true (if I return false the crash occurs). I agree as long as it works, it's better to make the default return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); Why it crashes is a mystery. I got it after an API34 upgrade with TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, mViewPager instead of Actionbar with tabs, and the tabs seem to react to this key (graying the first Tab after the first downkey) not other keys, Peculiar?

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem and solved it by adding

```
this.requestFocus();
this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

in the constructor of my SurfaceView subclass.

Comment: thanks, that worked for me. I was using a viewflipper to move between views, and wanted to override the back button to set a view as current view. Adding a webview to the VF stopped firing onKeyDown. Setting requestFocus and setFocusableInTouchMode on the VF sorted it out. Thanks again

Answer (score 6):

i solved removing the if statement, like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch(keyCode)
    {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA:
            videoPreview.TakePicture();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: yes good point. always returning false at the end used to work for me, but when compiling with new ICS SDK, the back key does not work any more as the event seems to be consumed now in super.onKeyDown

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why sometimes it does not work, though for one of my apps this `keyDown()` is working fine and again when I use it for a new app then it does not work.

But I have a solution which always works:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent (KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Back button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by adding into constructor this code:

```
setFocusable(true);
requestFocus();
```

thanks, [Ciryon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974680/android-onkeydown-problem#comment7757480_1818949)

Also every time I use `setContentView(myView);` I must call `myView.requestFocus();`. If there is a better solution please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in looking at the API documentation the only thing that stands out is that the android:clickable attribute must be set as well as the view being enabled for the onKeyDown(...) method to work.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
this.setFocusable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity could be eating the key event.  Override onKeyDown in the activity and throw a breakpoint in there.

Also: when you say you've "placed it in the main form" are you using the XML layout or doing in your code?